# How to add attributes from outside of the class?

Tags: python, oop

I know it's basic, but what is the best way to add attributes to class object from outside of that class?

Comment: The best way is not to do it. The second best way is `cls.new_attribute = value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by using the **dot** operator.  See [this link](http://reeborg.ca/docs/oop_py_en/oop.html) for more info

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

x = Thing()

x.attribute = "my attribute"

>>> print (x.attribute)
'my attribute'
```

Comment: Note he said **_class_** object, not class _instance_ object. So your example is wrong. The correct code would be `Thing.attribute = "my attribute"`.

Comment: Given the assumed skill level of op, I don't think this inaccuracy would matter in this context, but still a good catch.